# storing variable outside loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops

I am trying to store the result in my variable so I can reference it outside my loop and I cant get it work for the life of me, any help is greatly appreciated

see my code below

```
str = Dir['d:/Movies/**/*.mp4'].sort_by{ |f| File.ctime(f)  }.last(30)

movie_list = nil

str.each do |movie_list|
    movie_list = File.basename(movie_list)
end
puts movie_list
```

Comment: Maybe you want to map the basenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of #each:

```
movie_list = str.map do |movie_list|
  File.basename(movie_list)
end
```